# R Shiny non-numeric argument

Tags: r, shiny

I just started using shiny and there is the first problem when I run this code:

Shiny Server.R

```
library(shiny)

shinyServer(
function(input, output){


asset <- reactive(input$asset)
weight1 <- 0.3
weight2 <- 1-weight1

sum1 <- asset*weight1
```

Shiny UI.R:

```
library(shiny)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

titlePanel(title = "Programm"),
sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(("Asset 1:"),
           numericInput("asset:", "asset1:", 0, min=0, max=1000000)),
mainPanel(("xyz"),



         )

   )

))
```

The error says: non-numeric argument to binary operator. Is there a possibility to get numeric values out of the reactive function?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Possibly due to your variable being named `sum`, which is a base R function. You should avoid this in general.

Comment: Depends on what ui type is providing the input. You might want to wrap 'input$sum' in as.numeric()

Comment: It was no the sum. I used numeric input. What do you mean with as.numeric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Side note: Your code is sadly not really reproducible. Better code will make it more likely that you get an answer*

The problem is that `asset` is a reactive object. Hence you can not multiply it in the line `sum1 <- asset*weight1`.
This should be instead

```
sum1 <- reactive({asset()*weight1})
```

The total code can look like

```
shiny::shinyApp(shinyUI(fluidPage(

    titlePanel(title = "Programm"),
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(numericInput("asset", "asset1:", 0, min=0, max=1000000)),
        mainPanel(  textOutput("text1"))

    )

  )),
  shinyServer(
    function(input, output){
        asset <- reactive(input$asset)
        weight1 <- 0.3
        weight2 <- 1-weight1
        output$text1 <- reactive({asset()*weight1})
     }))
```